# Slow transfer using JSch from SFTP file transfer on Android

Tags: android, ssh, sftp, jsch, android-networking

I am using JSch to perform an SFTP download in Android. This is on a LAN with 802.11n and an SFTP server on a wired gigabit connection. I am getting about 8 mbytes/sec on a laptop (also 802.11n) with the same code but I am only getting 40kbytes/sec on Android. Are there some flags or something I need to turn on to get this to transfer faster? I have tried it on a Nexus 5 and a Nexus 6, both with 5.1. I tried a couple of apps and one downloaded the file at 230kbytes/sec and the other right around 40kbytes/sec so I'm guessing one of them has the same issue I do.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSch jsch = new JSch();

                    jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                    Session session = jsch.getSession("ftptest", "192.168.1.205");

                    session.setPort(22);
                    session.setPassword("password");
                    session.connect();
                    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
                    channel.connect();
                    SftpProgressMonitor monitor = new SftpProgressMonitor() {
                        long finalCount = 0;
                        long start = -1;

                        @Override
                        public void init(int op, String src, String dest, long max) {
                            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean count(long count) {
                            finalCount += count;
                          /*  long took = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;
                            if (took > 0) {
                                Log.w("SFTP", "Transferred so far " + finalCount + " at speed bytes/sec " + (finalCount / took));
                            }*/
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void end() {
                            long took = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;
                            Log.w("SFTP", "Transferred " + finalCount + " in " + took + " speed bytes/sec " + (finalCount  / took ));
                        }
                    };
                    InputStream stream = channel.get("file", monitor);
                    int read = -1;
                    byte[] bs = new byte[8192];
                    while((read = stream.read(bs)) >= 0){
                        //do nothing
                    }
                } catch (JSchException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SftpException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


}
```

EDIT: It seems to be much faster (about 160kbytes/sec) if I tell it to write the stream into a file without giving me an InputStream. The code looks pretty different between the two `get` methods but even if I went that route, 160kbytes/sec is still much slower than I had hoped.

Comment: You might be maxing out the hardware. See if you can collect CPU/IO data.

Comment: Maybe it is that, but I only see about 40% to 60% usage on my GS3 test device which performs the worst. The Nexus 4 and Nexus 6 get pretty similar speeds.

Comment: I have just confirmed it is not a hardware limitation, another library called sshj can download the files at over 1mbyte/sec.

Comment: Play around with new byte[8192]: Differ the size from 1k to 32k (1,2,4,8,16,32) to see if it makes a difference. Besides hardware you can also be running into latency, package fragmentation and the like on network level

Comment: I've tried many different sizes and also wrapping it on a buffer, none of it seems to help. I did get a lot better speed using their methods which download into an outputstream but it was still really slow compared to sshj.

Comment: Ok, with no obvious bottleneck on the hardware, the physical network layer (and your buffer tests), should be the bottleneck. Can you run your app in a simulator with your data file you are transferring on the same physical machine (ie: network is being ruled out). See if you get equal transfers times then?

Comment: I only did some quick tests on the emulator and it got about double the speed my Nexus 4 got but that is still several times slower than sshj. I am for now moving to sshj now that I have verified that it has all the functionality I need.

Comment: Ok, to bad no cause found. Succes

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you testing with?  Can you adb shell in and see what these settings are (when you're on wifi)?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
```

And then if they are low (something like "4092 8760 11680"), then try setting them to larger values:

```
sudo echo "524288,1048576,2097152" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
sudo echo "262144,524288,1048576" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
```

Then try your test again.

This could be from a bug where the wifi buffers were being set too small in some cases (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64706).

Comment: There's also an app to set these values for you (it still requires root access): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spirilis.bionictcp&hl=en

Comment: Hmm I'll see if I can find a device to test that on, none of my test devices are rooted.

Comment: Try cat'ing the files at least and you can see if they have small buffers set (you can do that without root I believe).

Comment: On Nexus 4 rmem has 524288 1048576 2097152 and wmem 262144 524288 1048576

Comment: Also I don't know if you saw the other messages I exchanged with someone else but basically other apps in the phone can get good speeds using SFTP as well and a library called sshj gets about 1 mbyte/sec on the same phone. I'm switching to sshj for now.

Comment: You could try a transfer without the progress monitor to see if there´s a difference.
Check the count parameter, if the count() method runs intensively with small data chunks it might have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your stream in a buffering stream?

```
 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(channel.get("file", monitor));
```

8192 bytes seems like a small buffer...

Also make sure you close your connections/streams, maybe you have a lot of outgoing connections you don't know about that's hogging the hardware?

Comment: Yeap I've tried wrapping it with several sizes. It happens on multiple phones, and I have killed every app I could on the phones before to test as well. Like I said on another comment, sshj is much faster so I am moving to that for now.